# I need your breeze more than I need your keys

Tags: idioms, idiom-meaning

What is **I need your breeze** referring to?

It's part of a song:

*I know I'm not supposed to look at you the way I look at you*

*I know I'm not supposed to look at you the way I look at you*

*I wear my shades all day long and I sing it in a folk song tune*

*You're not supposed to show, no you're not supposed to know the truth*

*'Cause boy, **I need your breeze** more than I need your keys*

(LikeLikeLike by Sophie Hunger)

Comment: We need your context more than we need your sentence.

Comment: @RegDwigнt added context, thanks

Comment: Could it be a reference to "shooting the breeze" meaning indulging in light talk? That would suggest that the subject of the song needed the other person's conversation and company more than sex and a serious relationship (assuming that the keys are the keys to the desired person's home)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find much information on usage of the term "breeze" in literature as a metaphor, so this answer comes entirely from personal thought rather than from examples.

I would take **your breeze** to mean **your aura**

> aura, noun
>
> > the distinctive atmosphere or quality that seems to surround and be generated by a person, thing, or place

The connection bridging to two of them being, that **your aura** and the saying **the air you have about you** have the same meaning; then using **breeze** instead of **the air you have** is a more fluent phrase, and more importantly, *breeze rhymes with keys*

> 'Cause boy, I need your **aura** more than I need your keys

Again, just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a reference to "shooting the breeze" meaning indulging in casual conversation. That would suggest that the narrator of the song needed the other person's conversation and company more than sex and a serious relationship.

Alternatively I have found a definition of "breeze" on the [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=breeze) site (admittedly not always the most authoritative source) which suggests that "breeze" can be slang for the physical attractiveness of an exceptionally beautiful young woman. It could be that it also works the other way and that an exceptionally attractive young *man* can be described as "breeze" or that it's a song about lesbian infatuation. Either way the narrator of the song seems to want the other person physically as opposed to entering a long term relationship.

In both the "shooting the breeze" and "breeze as sexual attraction" interpretations I'm assuming that "your keys" is a metaphor for a committed relationship with the keys being the keys to the desired person's home.